# Error: Unknown column 'catId' in 'from clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I have ran this script on WAMP and it works fine. When trying to upload it I got an error and unsure what it really means.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT forum_thread.threadId) AS 'threadTotal', COUNT(DISTINCT forum_posts.postId) AS 'postTotal'
FROM forum_cat
LEFT JOIN forum_posts USING (catId)
LEFT JOIN forum_thread USING (catId)
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.userId = forum_posts.userId
GROUP BY forum_cat.catId
```

that's the SQL script which runs fine in WAMP; online I get the following error

> Notice: Query: SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT forum_thread.threadId) AS 'threadTotal', COUNT(DISTINCT forum_posts.postId) AS 'postTotal' FROM forum_cat LEFT JOIN forum_posts USING (catId) LEFT JOIN forum_thread USING (catId) LEFT JOIN users ON users.userId = forum_posts.userId GROUP BY catId 
>   MySQL Error: Unknown column 'catId' in 'from clause'

Comment: I suspect it is a MyISAM table and you upload from a non case-sensitive system (win) to a case-sensitive system (linux). Run `DESC forum_cat`, `DESC forum_posts` and `DESC forum_thread` on the target system and keep lookout for `CatId`, `catID` or friends.

Comment: @alex Sorry it was forum_cat.catId

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what's wrong. There is no such column. Probably you failed to recreate the table schema exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be you have `catid` column is in more then one tables you joining that conflicting so use `alias` with column names

Try below:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT ft.threadId) AS 'threadTotal', COUNT(DISTINCT fp.postId) AS 'postTotal'
FROM forum_cat as fc
LEFT JOIN forum_posts as fp USING(fp.catId)
LEFT JOIN forum_thread as ft USING(ft.catId)
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.userId = fp.userId
GROUP BY fc.catId
```

Comment: I get an error if I use that.

I changed mine slightly and removed the forum_posts and it returns fine. I think it might be conflicting USING(catId) 

'SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT forum_thread.threadId) AS 'threadTotal'
FROM forum_cat
LEFT JOIN forum_thread USING (catId)
LEFT JOIN users ON forum_thread.userId = users.userId
GROUP BY forum_cat.catId
    ORDER BY forum_cat.catId ASC'

That's the revised code but obviously not exactly what I am after

Comment: Notice: Query: SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT ft.threadId) AS 'threadTotal', COUNT(DISTINCT fp.postId) AS 'postTotal' FROM forum_cat as fc LEFT JOIN forum_posts as fp USING (fp.catId) LEFT JOIN forum_thread as ft USING (ft.catId) LEFT JOIN users ON users.userId = forum_posts.userId GROUP BY fc.catId 
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.catId) LEFT JOIN forum_thread as ft USING (ft.catId) LEFT JOIN users ON use' at line 3 in /home/scotty/public_html/forums/index.php on line 17

Comment: try to use on clause instead of using

Comment: Using the on clause I get 'Notice: Query: SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT forum_thread.threadId) AS 'threadTotal', COUNT(DISTINCT forum_posts.postId) AS 'postTotal' FROM forum_cat LEFT JOIN forum_thread ON forum_thread.catId = forum_cat.catId LEFT JOIN forum_posts ON forum_posts.catId = forum_thread.catId LEFT JOIN users ON forum_thread.userId = users.userId GROUP BY forum_cat.catId ORDER BY forum_cat.catId ASC 
MySQL Error: Unknown column 'forum_posts.catId' in 'on clause' in /home/scotty/public_html/forums/index.php on line 18'

Comment: see colum name is it catId or catid? "i" capital. make it same as u have in table

Comment: Column name is catId with capital I

Comment: I think that's a sign of bed time. Thank you I obviously tested everything on WAMP but forgot to change it on the server, sorry about that, Thank for all your help.